# Ajustar ancho de un Div al 100% de toda la pantalla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de hacer que los `div` con clase `content-can` se adapten a todo el ancho de la pantalla, ambos deben tener el mismo estilo y que estén uno encima del otro, tengo el siguiente `código`:

PD: El contenido solo se puede modificar agregando html o css, la estructura que se tiene no se puede eliminar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">
        <div style="position: relative; padding: 10px 50px;">
            <div class="content-can" style="height: 220px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 43px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 43px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 86px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="content-can" style="height: 220px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El título y la pregunta no coinciden y no deja las cosas muy claras: ¿quieres que estén al 100% de la pantalla o al 100% del padre que, casualmente, ocupará toda la pantalla?

Comment: @PabloLozano Que esten al 100% de la pantalla windows

Comment: Entonces deberías quitar el `position:relative` al padre porque sino usará ese `div` como referencia

Comment: @blonfu Pero entonces no queda dentro del elemento **div padre**

Comment: los elementos `div` por defecto son de tamaño 100% del ancho del padre con altura acorde al contenido y son apilados (uno encima del otro). Si no están del 100% del ancho de la pantalla es porque el padre es de tamaño menor

Answer (score 2):

Si no se puede modificar el HTML y solo se puede con CSS, entonces hay que hacer un override de los estilos de Bootstrap, básicamente el de la clase container, para ajustar su ancho a 100% y dejando los valores de padding a izquierda y derecha en 0.

**NOTA: en este caso fue necesario utilizar el incómodo `!important` para que funcione en el snippet, sin embargo y dependiendo como se defina o agregue el CSS, no es necesario.**

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">
        <div style="position: relative; padding: 10px 50px;">
            <div class="content-can" style="height: 220px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 43px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 43px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 86px; background-color: #000;margin: 5px;"></div>
            <div class="content-can" style="height: 220px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -1;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me has dado una idea.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas usando Bootstrap te dejo esta solución.

El problema es que estas usando container en tu contenedor padre, al usar esta clase estas definiendo un Max-width: determinado por el framework, para que abarque todo el viewport de la página debes retirar la clase CONTAINER.

Comment: no es necesario que si ya respondiste una vez, elimines esa respuesta y agregues otra; en su lugar edita la originla y ahi coloca lo que te falta

Comment: No se debe modificar la estructura, es necesario que sea tal cual, solo se debe modificar agregando contenido html o css

Comment: Si desea que no abarque deberia ser asi, o puede simplemente cambiar el diseño con css y queda bien.